# Is it possible to get outbound client request information in ClientHeadersFactory?

Tags: quarkus, resteasy, microprofile

I am writing an application with the following layers:

`External Client (e.g. browser) -> My Service -> External API`

I have a `ClientHeadersFactory` which adds some headers to the REST Client I use in `My Service` to call `External API`. I was wondering whether it was possible to get information about the client request from my REST Client in `My Service` to `External API`? For example, I'd like to know the HTTP method and the endpoint my REST Client is calling. This will impact what headers I add.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClientHeadersFactory` is not designed for use cases where looking into the request is necessary.
To add headers based on the request, you can use `ClientRequestFilter`.

Note, that you can mix `ClientHeadersFactory` with filters.

For example, you could do something like this:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(requestContext.getMethod())) {
            requestContext.getHeaders().add("MyHeader", "POST-specific header");
        }
    }
}
```

You can register such a filter for a single client, by annotating the client with `@RegisterProvider(MyFilter.class)`, or, if you use `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`, for all the clients in your application by adding the `@Provider` annotation **to the filter**.